# How to write a monad that prints "step i of N" when executing each statement in the monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, template-haskell

I'm not even sure this is possible in any kind of monad; does it violate monad laws?  But it seems like something that should be possible in some kind of construct or other.  Specifically is there any way to have something that I can write something like

```
do
  someOp ()
  someOtherOp ()
  thirdOp ()
```

and it would print

```
step 1 of 3
step 2 of 3
step 3 of 3
```

Would this require Template Haskell or would a monad work?  (And if Template Haskell is required, how to do it that way?)

Comment: Oh you can, you just need a monad that passes the state along, the state being a count!

Comment: I won't write in an answer since I'm not sure but I would think that it would be possible to at least print the increment. Printing the "of 3" over and over means that 3 must be put into a variable unless it is passed through the monad as sortof a second, immutable argument (though it's all technically immutable...). So my intuition says yes it's definitely possible, perhaps not trivial, and I highly doubt the working code would look like the sequential calls you used as an example.

Comment: @Skurmedel that gives the i, but whence the N?

Comment: @jm0 Yeah the `N` is the main problem.  I really only included the `i` because the question would look silly without it.

Comment: Well I will give up because I don't know Haskell (I'm learning Clojure which is less pure I think) so I doubt you want to wait several hours for me to try my hand at this. But i'm pretty sure of this much -- recursive function, 2 arguments (i,N), i is incremented for the recursion, recursion terminates when i==N. oh & good luck! i'm sure functional/list processing is a really powerful tool, i'm just starting off as well

Comment: @jm0 Yeah it's interesting because this is fairly trivial to do in Clojure using `defmacro`.  Not sure how to do it just using monads though.

Comment: @lobsterism The problem comes in when with those monadic actions you're calling.  Do you print out the step counts for each of them as well?  Do you add those to the total count?  How do you determine the total count, anyway?  I think what would suit your needs better would be a logger library or a debugger.

Comment: @bheklir Just the top-level ones.  But that's kind of where I'm not really sure where it would follow monadic laws.  If you inlined the functions, the count could be different, and would that violate the laws?  Thus if so, would Template Haskell work and how?

Comment: @lobsterism But how could a macro calculate the total number of steps  that would be performed?

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete A macro takes a list of expressions, so can count that list, and return a list interspersed with `(print i of N)` expressions.  Anything you can do with a list, you can do with your AST in a macro.  Or if you wanted to count down to the leaves you could write a macro that intersperses a tree.  Of course that only applies to the exact AST you pass in, so if you inline/extract functions then that changes the behavior.  (Which is what I want).

Comment: @lobsterism: Sorry, I missed that part :(

Comment: @lobsterism The macro you describe would work with lists of isolated statements. But what happens if one expression takes as a parameter the result of an earlier expression?

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete Since you'd have to do that in a `let` expression anyway it'll work as specified, but yeah it becomes of limited utility at that point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that you want the steps to be displayed automatically, without having to sprinkle you code with logging statements.

The problem of doing this with monads is that they are *too* flexible: at any point, the "shape" of the rest of the computation can depend on values obtained during the computation itself. This is made explicit in the type of `(>>=)`, which is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

As a consequence, there is no fixed number `N` of total steps that you can know before running the computation.

However, Haskell offers two other abstractions which trade some of the power and flexibility of monads for the chance to perform a greater amount of "static" analysis beforehand: [applicative functors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Applicative) and [arrows](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Arrow).

Applicative functors, while hugely useful, are perhaps too "weak" for your needs. You can´t write a function inside an applicative functor that, when applied to a value, prints that value to console. This is explained in the paper ["Idioms are oblivious, arrows are meticulous, monads are promiscuous"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/arrows-and-idioms/arrows-and-idioms.pdf) which contains some enlightening examples of the limits of each abstraction (applicative functors are called "idioms" in that paper.)

Arrows offer a better compromise between expressive power and amenability to static analysis. The "shape" of arrow computations is fixed in a static pipeline. Data obtained during the computation can influence effects later in the pipeline (for example, you can print a value obtained by a previous effect in the computation) but *not* change the shape of the pipeline, or the number of steps.

So, if you could express your computation using [Kleisli arrows](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli) (the arrows of a monad), perhaps you could write some kind of arrow transformer (*not* monad transformer) which added automated logging capabilities.

The [arrows](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1) package offers a number of arrow transformers. I think [StaticArrow](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.1/docs/Control-Arrow-Transformer-Static.html) could be used to automatically track the total number of steps. But you would still need to write some functionality to actually emit the messages.

**Edit:** Here's an example of how to keep count of the number of steps in a computation, using arrows:

```
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Arrow.Transformer
import Control.Arrow.Transformer.Static

type SteppedIO a b = StaticArrow ((,) (Sum Int)) (Kleisli IO) a b

step :: (a -> IO b) -> SteppedIO a b
step cmd = wrap (Sum 1, Kleisli cmd)

countSteps :: SteppedIO a b -> Int
countSteps = getSum . fst . unwrap

exec :: SteppedIO a b -> a -> IO b
exec =  runKleisli . snd . unwrap 

program :: SteppedIO () ()
program =
    step (\_ -> putStrLn "What is your name?")  
    >>>
    step (\_ -> getLine)
    >>>
    step (putStrLn . mappend "Hello, ")

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "Number of steps: " ++ show (countSteps program)
    exec program ()
```

Notice that the effect of step 3 is influenced by a value produced in step 2. This can't be done using applicatives.

We do use the `(,) (Sum Int)` applicative, required by `StaticArrow` to encode the static information (here, just the number of steps).

Displaying the steps as they are executed would require a bit more work.

**Edit#2** If we are dealing with a sequence of commands in which no effect depends on a value produced by a previous effect, then we can avoid using arrows and count the steps using only applicative functors:

```
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Functor.Compose

type SteppedIO a = Compose ((,) (Sum Int)) IO a

step :: IO a -> SteppedIO a
step cmd = Compose (Sum 1, cmd)

countSteps :: SteppedIO a -> Int
countSteps = getSum . fst . getCompose

exec :: SteppedIO a -> IO a
exec =  snd . getCompose

program :: SteppedIO () 
program =
    step (putStrLn "aaa") 
    *>  
    step (putStrLn "bbb")
    *>
    step (putStrLn "ccc")

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ "Number of steps: " ++ show (countSteps program)
    exec program
```

`Data.Functor.Compose` comes from the `transformers` package.

**Edit#3** The following code extends the previous `Applicative` step counting solution, using the `pipes` package to actually emit notifications. The arrow-based solution could be adapted in a similar manner.

```
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Functor.Compose
import Pipes
import Pipes.Lift

type SteppedIO a = Compose ((,) (Sum Int)) (Producer () IO) a

step :: IO a -> SteppedIO a
step cmd = Compose (Sum 1, yield () *> lift cmd)

countSteps :: SteppedIO a -> Int
countSteps = getSum . fst . getCompose

exec :: SteppedIO a -> Producer () IO a
exec =  snd . getCompose

stepper :: MonadIO m => Int -> Consumer () m a
stepper n = evalStateP 0 $ forever $ do 
    await
    lift $ modify succ
    current <- lift get
    liftIO $ putStrLn $ "step " ++ show current ++ " of " ++ show n

program :: SteppedIO () 
program = *** does not change relative to the previous example ***

main :: IO ()
main = runEffect $ exec program >-> stepper (countSteps program)
```

Comment: Can you provide some kind of example?  My gut is telling me this is the right way to go about this but at my current level this looks like several days worth of work, with a 49% chance of this being the wrong path entirely.

Comment: I have recently written "plan-applicative" a library that implements this pattern: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/plan-applicative

Answer (score 5):

While I think Daniel Díaz' arrow solution is he perfect way to do this, there is sure enough a simpler one (which, I just see, he also indicates in the comments already) provided, as in your example, no data is passed *between* the different function calls.

Remember that, since Haskell is lazy, functions can do lots of stuff that would require macros in other languages. In particular, it's no problem whatsoever to have a list of `IO` actions. (Absolutely safe, too: due to pureness, there's no way these could "go off early" in Haskell!) Then you can simply take the length of this list as the total count, interleave it with printing statements, and be done. All in the core language, don't need TH!

```
sequenceWithStepCount :: [IO()] -> IO()
sequenceWithStepCount actions = go actions 0
 where nTot = length actions
       go [] _ = putStrLn "Done!"
       go (act:remains) n = do
             putStrLn ("Step "++show n++" of "++show nTot)
             act
             go remains $ succ n
```

To be used like

```
do
 sequenceWithStepCount [
     someOp ()
   , someOtherOp ()
   , thirdOp ()
   ]
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is actually what I do in C# currently and have each step modify a bunch of mutable member variables, was curious whether some monadic solution would enable the same functionality without the need for mutables.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that this might violate the laws, depending on what you mean.

For example, if `return` were to count as a step, then you'd have a violation because the first monad law would not hold:

```
do x <- return  /=  f x
   f x
```

Similarly, if abstracting out two steps into another named function counts as removing a step, then you also violate the monad laws, because the third monad law would not hold:

```
m' = do x <- m
        f x

do y <- m'  /=  do x <- m
   g y             y <- f x
                   g y
```

However, if you have commands explicitly emit the "step" output, then there is no violation.  This is because `return` could then not emit any output at all, and sequencing two commands would just add their step outputs together.  Here's an example:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

step :: StateT Int IO ()
step = do
    n <- get
    lift $ putStrLn $ "Step " ++ show n
    put (n + 1)

command1 = do
    command1'  -- The command1 logic without the step behavior
    step

command2 = do
    command2'
    step

-- etc.
```

Note that I don't include the total number of steps.  There's no way to have access to that information for a monad.  For that I recommend Daniel's answer, because `Applicative`s are an excellent solution to this problem of determining the number of steps statically without any Template Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of logger libraries.

If you are interested in Monad-Logger - here you are: [Control.Monad.Logger](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-logger-0.3.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Logger.html)

And at the [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=logger) you could find other libraries

Comment: Thanks but I don't see anything remotely related to step counting there.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [monad transformer](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html) to stack on a WriterT that counts how many `>>`'s and `>>=`'s have been applied to the underlying monad.

Comment: Can you include an example?  I'm fairly new to Haskell and can't really say I fully understand monads, and *zero* understanding of monad transformers.

Comment: I can write an example for "Step 1:" but I can't for "i of n", because the meaning of "n" depends on what you're doing in your monad, as Daniel has more eruditely pointed out. Thus it's really incumbent on you to understand monad transformation. If your monad is amenable to analysis - i.e., each >> always results in another step - then you don't need to go to the work of ripping out your structure and replacing it with arrows. Meanwhile, if it isn't amenable, then you can't go to the work of replacing it with arrows.

Comment: Another comment. "Step i of n" just *is* a special case of logging, so I really think you should look at wit's answer again. It may not exactly solve your problem, but a logger transformer is just a conveniently bundled up stack of monad transformers that provide a logging API to pass messages and execute IO actions orthogonally to the execution of the underlying monad - which is what you're trying to do.